# Maven doesn't compile webapp

Tags: java, maven, jakarta-ee, web-applications, jetty

Before I made a simple dynamic web project with websockets and without maven, it works fine. Now I try to use maven. But when I'm compiling my project with `mvn compile jetty:run` it doesn't build with `javax.servlet.UnavailableException: Servlet class com.example.testbattle.ServerSide is not a javax.servlet.Servlet` exception. It requires to implement Servlet interface. Why didn't I need it with simple dynamic web project. How could I avoid this problem?

**UPDATE**: I have found out the problem it was wrong web.xml Now I can't launch serverside. What should I put into web.xml?

Comment: You should try `mvn clean package` and if this is sucessfull try `mvn jetty:run`.

Comment: before `mvn clean install` or after?

Comment: I have tried that doesn't work. Still same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such an error reports that you are trying to register pass an **non servlet** class as a servlet one, meaning here that obviousely `com.example.testbattle.ServerSide` does not implement `javax.servlet.Servlet` or extend a subclass of it.

If `com.example.testbattle.ServerSide` is intended to be your Servlet application entry point then go ahead an implement the mentioned interface and all its derived methods (`onService`...).