# How compose web.xml to lauch server side with maven and jetty

Tags: java, xml, maven, jakarta-ee, web.xml

What should I put into web.xml to launch to start server side. I launch jetty but only ui works server side isn't not running

I have next folder tree:

```
src
  |-main
      |-java
      |    |-com
      |        |-example
      |                |-test
      |                     |-ServerSide.java
      |-webapp
             |-index.html
             |-WEB-INF
                     |-web.xml
```

Server side class

```
package com.example.test;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.websocket.OnOpen;
import javax.websocket.Session;
import javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint;


@ServerEndpoint("/testbattle")
public class ServerSide {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
        System.out.println("Welcome" + new Date());
        session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello websockets");  
    }
}
```

Comment: I assume that `web.sml` is just a typo and the file is really named `web.xml`, right? Anyways, if `ServerSide` is a servlet, you should put `servlet` and `servlet-mapping` elements in your web.xml. Or you could use `@WebServlet` annotation on your servlet class in which case you wouldn't need to specify anything in web.xml.

Comment: Yes, you are right, it was a typo. But when I put `servlet` into web.xml it requires to implement servlet. And it causes antoher problem which I discribed in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26690910/maven-doesnt-compile-webapp

Comment: Well that is logical. If you register servlet in web.xml it must actually be a servlet. Could you share the code of your ServerSide class?

Comment: I just can't understand the difference beetwen a dynamic web project which doesn't require to implement servlet and maven web project which does

Comment: OK I was under the impression that ServerSide was a plain-old HTTP Servlet not Websocket endpoint. In that case you don't need to implement Servlet interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If all what you care about is launching you server side endpoint, then you can just add a `main` method which will be you application entry, but note that this won't let jetty maven plugin to run you application because jetty is a web container thus based on servlets.

```
package com.example.websocket;

import org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.DefaultServlet;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletContextHandler;
import org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder;
import org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.jsr356.server.deploy.WebSocketServerContainerInitializer;

public class ServerStarter {
  public static void main( String[] args ) throws Exception {
  Server server = new Server(8080);

  final ServletHolder servletHolder = new ServletHolder(new DefaultServlet());
  final ServletContextHandler context = new ServletContextHandler();

  context.setContextPath("/");
  context.addServlet(servletHolder, "/*");

  server.setHandler(context);
  WebSocketServerContainerInitializer.configureContext(context); 

  server.start();
  server.join(); 
  }
}
```

If you are intending to use websockets in a plain web app, you have to register a websocket handler (which should be `ServerSide` in you case) to `JettyServlet` (which should be of subtype ``) and register the latter (`JettyServlet`) into the *web.xml* file and not the `ServerSide` class:

- *web.xml*:

  ```
  <web-app>
    <display-name>WebSocketApp</display-name>
    <servlet>
      <servlet-name>wsservlet</servlet-name>
      <servlet-class>com.example.test.MyJettyServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>wsservlet</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
  ```
- *MyJettyServlet*:

  ```
  package com.example.test;

  public class MyJettyServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
      factory.register(ServerSide.class);
    }
  }
  ```
- *ServerSide*:

  ```
  @WebSocket
  public class ServerSide {
    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) throws IOException {
      System.out.println("Welcome" + new Date());
      session.getBasicRemote().sendText("Hello websockets");  
    }
  }
  ```

Comment: So when I create dynamic web project with eclipse and use servlets containers this things are being created automatically, aren't they?

Comment: Kind of that, the web container will manage your servlets but it will be up to you to tell you servlet to act like a back end web socket endpoint, that by creating you own servlet as explained.